# Evaluate the following limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to evaluate that limit: $$\lim_{x\to\
1} \frac{\sqrt {x+3}+\sqrt x -3 }{\sqrt {x^2+3}+\sqrt x -3}$$
My idea is to split  the terms as this: $\sqrt {x+3}-2+\sqrt x -1   $ and $\sqrt {x^2+3}-2+\sqrt x -1$ but i dont know how to continue. The result is $ -\frac {17 }{24}  $

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule makes it 3/4. What's your source for -17/24?

Comment: Your idea is good. To continue, write $\sqrt{x+3}-2=(x-1)/(\sqrt{x+3}+2)$, $\sqrt{x}-1=(x-1)/(\sqrt{x}+1)$, etc, and simplify by $x-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice we can rewrite the numerator and denominator as

$$\begin{align}
\verb/numerator/ 
&= (\sqrt{x+3} - 2) + (\sqrt{x}-1)
= \frac{(x+3)-4}{\sqrt{x+3}+2} + \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\\
&= (x-1)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}+2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\right)\\
\verb/denominator/
&= (\sqrt{x^2+3}-2) + (\sqrt{x}-1)
= \frac{(x^2+3)-4}{\sqrt{x^2+3}+2} + \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\\
&= (x-1)\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+3}+2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$
The complicated ratio we have equals to
$$\frac{
\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}+2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+1}
}{
\displaystyle\;\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+3}+2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+1}
}
\quad\to\quad
\frac{
\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{2+2} + \frac{1}{1+1}
}{
\displaystyle\;\frac{1+1}{2+2} + \frac{1}{1+1}
}
= \frac34
\quad\text{ as }x \to 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the expression takes indeterminate form $({0 \over 0})$ as $x \to 1$, we have to use L'Hôpital's rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). Taking the derivatives of numerator and denominator the answer comes out to be ${3\over 4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt {x+3}, g(x) = \sqrt x, h(x) = \sqrt {x^2+3}.$ The expression equals

$$\frac{[f(x)-f(1)]+[g(x) - g(1)] }{[h(x) — h(1)]+[g(x)-g(1)]} =\frac{[f(x)-f(1)]/(x-1)+[g(x) - g(1)]/(x-1) }{[h(x) — h(1)]/(x-1)+[g(x)-g(1)]/(x-1)}.$$

By the definition of the derivative, the limit of this as $x\to 1$ is
$[f'(1)+g'(1)]/[h'(1)+g'(1)].$ (Note: We are not using L'Hopital.)